# Не записывается дата в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть форма регистрации, через input данные заносятся в БД, но значение даты не заносится.

```
<input type="date" name="birthdate">

$birthdate= $_POST['birthdate'];
 mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `users2` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`,`birthdate`,  `reportSubject`, `phone`,`email`, `company`, `position`, `aboutMe`, `photo`) VALUES (NULL, '$firstname', '$lastname','$birthdate', '$reportSubject','$phone','$email', '$company', '$position', '$aboutMe', '$path')");
```

В таблице колонка birthdate с типом date

Comment: потому что чтобы дата записалсь в БД, она должна иметь **определенный формат**

Comment: Подскажите какой, и как это сделать?

Comment: ну, "какой" можно посмотреть в учебнике, а "как" - в гугле.